# Simple UPDATE taking too long at first, then speeding up

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

In what situation would a simple update statement

```
UPDATE [BasicUserTable] 
SET [DateTimeCol] = '9/6/2022'
WHERE [UniqueIntPKCol] = 123
```

take **1m 30s** to complete, AND THEN all subsequent updates using the same statement and lines of code (except for id and datetime), execute in < 100 ms?

The table has less than 10,000 records, standard int auto incrementing primary key.

Background: our app was timing out (standard 30 sec timeout) while it waited for SQL Server to execute the statement above. We manually tried the statement using SSMS on the same server, and it took ~1m 30s to execute.

Immediately afterward, all other attempts to run the same code were blazing fast as expected. We can't walk past this issue without knowing the real reason that it happened, so we can prevent it in the future.

- After looking at logs, there were no apparent blocking locks on the records, nor code that could intervene an cause issue.
- SQL Logs did not have any errors

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
> Inner exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Has anyone run into this before, or do you have a plausible working theory? (index rebuild, caching, etc.)

Comment: Have you inspected the execution plan? And turned `statistics` on?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a transaction left hanging by a previous process? Sometimes this can be caused by poor back-out code, such as missing `using` blocks

Answer (score 1):

A lock wait is the only thing I can imagine that would cause this.

> After looking at logs, there were no apparent blocking locks

Lock waits don't cause any logging.  You might see logs if you configure the [blocked process report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/blocked-process-report-event-class?view=sql-server-ver16), but it's not on by default.

Turning on the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16) can help by helping track query resource utilization and waits.

Although extremely unlikely here, file growth can also cause sporadic delays, as the statement that needs the additional log file or data file space has to wait for the file to be resized.

Comment: I've also had lockups when the NVME drive basically stalled

Comment: Yes.  Very bad storage problems can cause this.  Also paging-out of the SQL Server process.  But both IO stalls and excessive paging generate log entries.